# 500 internal sever error While referring a file in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, filepath

I am facing a problem 500 internal server error while referring a file through PHP

**Here is my code**

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf.class.php');
?>
```

Here I am having the class file in the same folder itself...

Comment: What error message appears in log?

Comment: there is nothing in server log but in browser it is displaying 500 internal server error .................

Comment: Check if you have error logging enabled. Every single 500 error should generate a line in the logs. No exceptions.

Comment: try turning error reporting on so you can see what the error is.

Comment: Does anything change when you remove/comment this string? What is inside of that file?

Comment: in php.in error log is on only... like this we have to give know....`log_errors = On`

Answer (score 1):

Check the ownership and group for the files giving the error, and the accessrights of the directory they are in. Most probably your webserver cannot access these files.
You can change the ownership using:

```
chown username:groupname filename
```

where username is the webservers username, and groupname is the webserver's groupname.

Comment: where i have to give this line?

Comment: On the command line of your webserver. If you do not have access to it, you could try an FTP program such as filezilla, or ask the sysadmin.

Comment: this will support in localhost?

Answer (score 1):

In your *php.ini* :

- if you want an output of the errors : set `display_errors` to **On**
- if you want to see the errors in your log file : set the `log_errors`  to **On** and the `error_log` to a **string file path**  (exemple: error_log = /var/log/php-scripts.log)

You could find the different parameters of php.ini runtime configuration [here](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log).

After the restart of your web server, if you fall into an unexpected 500 error; **it may be because of the "@" operator**: from the documentation:

*Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.*

And nothing to do but in php5.3 you can do: ( [`__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.constants.predefined.php) )

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/html2pdf.class.php');
?>
```

Comment: did you restart your web server? Otherwise the configuration is not taken into consideration

Comment: i didn't changed anything in my `php.ini` before i am asking here as a question it is on only.....

Comment: _To view correctly which errors come from this page; you have to change the php.ini and to restart your server._. However, the error came **either from the fact the file** _html2pdf.class.php_ **didn't exist**, **or because something is wrong in the code of the** _html2pdf.class.php_.